# Trying to solve a date discrepancy issue with timezone-aware data filtered from a csv between two dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timezone, datetime64

My problem is in finding the best-practice to resolve the issue of including all requested timezone-aware dates in a selected range. Depending on how I approach it, either the *enddate* or the *startdate* fail to return their date from the csv. I cannot get both to work at the same time without tricking the code (which seems like bad coding practice, and might produce issues if the user is entering dates while browsing from a different timezone locale).

In its simplest form, I am trying to return the complete year of 2021 transaction records from a csv file. The URL call to FastAPI to run the code is this:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/portfolio/tastytx?year=2021

When the user enters the *year* parameter in the URL the *enddate* and *startdate* get set, then the csv read into a dataframe, the dataframe filtered, and a json returned. In the following code snippet, *'frame'* is the dataframe from *pd.read_csv* code that is not shown:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pytz import timezone
import pytz
import json 
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
        
startdate = year +'-01-01'
enddate = year + '-12-31'
        
startdate = dt.datetime.strptime(startdate, '%Y-%m-%d') #convert string to a date
startdate = startdate.replace (tzinfo=pytz.utc) #convert date to UTC and make it timezone-aware
enddate = dt.datetime.strptime(enddate, '%Y-%m-%d')        
enddate = enddate.replace (tzinfo=pytz.utc)       
  
frame['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(frame['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d') #turns 'Date' from object into datetime64 
frame['Date'] = frame['Date'].dt.tz_convert('UTC') #converts csv 'Date' column to UTC from AEST(+10)

selectdf = frame.loc[frame['Date'].between(startdate, enddate, inclusive=True)] #filters time period      

return Response(selectdf.to_json(orient="records"), media_type="application/json")
```

**The csv file containing the data has 'Date' column in AEST timezone (i.e. UTC+10).**

In my code I convert everything to UTC and then do the comparison, but with the above code the date for 1st Jan 2021 is not returned, the 2nd Jan is. What is the right way to solve this, I have tried every configuration of timezone changes and so far nothing returned both 1st Jan 2021 and 31st Dec 2021 at the same time.

Sample data:

the csv file from 'Date' Column :

> ```
> Date
> 2021-12-31T01:35:59+1000
> 2021-12-31T01:35:59+1000
> 2021-12-31T01:09:57+1000
> 2021-12-31T01:09:57+1000
> 2021-12-30T03:02:25+1000
> 2021-12-30T01:52:58+1000
> ...
> 2021-01-02T00:48:29+1000
> 2021-01-01T02:40:03+1000
> 2021-01-01T00:30:00+1000
> 2021-01-01T00:30:00+1000
> ```

**There is some confusion about the issue:**

to clarify the problem, the above code will return the following epoch time (startdate) as the first record: 1609512509000 and the following epoch time (enddate) as the date of the last record: 1640878559000

For me it is translating that as 2nd Jan (I am in AEST timezone in my browser) and 31st Dec respectively, and so the json returned from the above csv data is 2nd Jan to 31st Dec, thus incorrect.

If you run it in your browser it will likely return those epoch dates records relevant to your timezone. This is my problem.

Comment: please add sample data including the Jan 1st and Dec last dates.

Comment: What timezone is the data in, is it single or mixed? If it's mixed, you'll need to clarify expected behaviour first...

Comment: timezone is AEST(+10) as mentioned, but the FastAPI can be called from a browser that might be in any timezone the csv data remains in AEST. There is some code from csv copy and pasted into the question now.

Comment: Try `enddate = enddate.replace(hour=23,minute=59,second=59)`

Comment: @MarkRansom that wont solve it. I have added a note at the end about exactly what is happening.

Comment: So it appears you really don't want UTC dates.  So why are you using UTC in your logic?

Comment: @MarkRansom I take it back. I think you may have solved it. I had overcomplicated everything and confused my own logic, I am just testing it but it looks like I only needed to convert the enddate and startdate to AEST (not the csv data) and then apply your suggested fix. please add it as an answer and I will close it.